# Nothing to commit on git, but I have some changes on my branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, phpstorm, push

I make some changes in project, but I cannot commit on git on my branch (another instead of branch master).

I've made a pull request from master and from that I cannot commit on git:

```
marius@marius-Aspire-A515-51G:~/Proiecte/picboard-frontend-react$ git commit -a -m "wip"
On branch marius
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What can I make on this case?

Comment: What kind of changes have you made that you would like to commit?

Comment: About some code

Comment: Are you sure the file is inside the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the modified file is inside your local Git repository, make sure said file is not ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/modified/file
```

If it is ignored, it would not be added/committed.
(or you would need to force the git add: `git addd -f -- a/file`, then commit)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my guesses:

1. You stashed your changes and did not unstash them; or
2. The changes are already committed:

   - In a commit you forgot about; or
   - inside the merge commit that was created when integrating `master`.

This is based you say that you have *made a pull request from master*.